# Geometry: What is being calculated here?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

Context: I am a computer graphics programmer looking at a code-implementation. I need help understanding a function that has neither been documented properly nor commented.

Given a circle with circumference $c$ in a Cartesian coordinate space. Now each point on this circle is defined by Cartesian coordinates $(x, y)$.

I need some explanations as to what the following calculations achieve, please excuse the improper use of symbols:

---

$$
\begin{align}
nX = \frac {x}{c}\\
nY = \frac {y}{c}
\end{align}
$$

I believe $n$ stands for 'normal' or vector. then...

---

$$
\begin{align}
rdX = nX \cdot 2\pi\\
rdY = nY \cdot \pi
\end{align}
$$

I assume 'rd' stands for radians. What really puzzles me here is why nX is multiplied with $2\pi$, while $nY$ is only multiplied by $\pi$.

---

$$
\begin{align}
\sin Y = \sin(rdY + \pi)
\end{align}
$$

At this point I'm completely lost...

---

now finally:
$$
\begin{align}
a = 2\pi\cdot\sin(rdX)\cdot\sin Y\\
b = 2\pi\cdot\cos(rdX)\cdot\sin Y\\
d = 2\pi\cdot\cos(rdy)
\end{align}
$$

---

Very simple question; What is being calculated here? What do a,b and d represent? At first i figured that this was a conversion from Cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates. But given a closer look, this is not at all how I would calculate them. What am I looking at here?

---

**EDIT:**

I will include the source of these calculations to clarify their context. They are part of a library that provides functions for working with [Simplex Noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_noise).

They appear in functions that **sample** a generated noise field. This noise field can be sampled in n-dimensions. This sampling means that I provide a set of parameters (usually coordinates) to the noise functions, which return a noise value, eg:

```
var noiseValue = simplexNoise.get2DNoise( x, y )
var noiseValue = simplexNoise.get3DNoise( x, y, z )
var noiseValue = simplexNoise.get4DNoise( x, y, z, w )
```

An example:

If I generate a grid of points in a plane dimension (two dimensions), and then sample noise values of those points using their coordinates:

```
z = simplexNoise.get2DNoise( x, y )
```

Then now I suddenly have a **third** dimension. This to say i started with [this](http://www.thedevilisinthecode.com/uploads/2/1/3/4/21342158/4798936_orig.jpg), and ended up sampling my z values to result in [this](http://www.thedevilisinthecode.com/uploads/2/1/3/4/21342158/5307323.jpg?347). The noise function assures me that I do not have completely random values.

---

Now however, I want to sample noise on a **spherical** surface. And I encounter these two functions:

```
FastSimplexNoise.prototype.getSpherical2DNoise = function (c, x, y) {
  var nx = x / c;
  var ny = y / c;
  var rdx = nx * 2 * Math.PI;
  var rdy = ny * Math.PI;
  var sinY = Math.sin(rdy + Math.PI);
  var sinRds = 2 * Math.PI;
  var a = sinRds * Math.sin(rdx) * sinY;
  var b = sinRds * Math.cos(rdx) * sinY;
  var d = sinRds * Math.cos(rdy);

  return this.get3DNoise(a, b, d);
};

FastSimplexNoise.prototype.getSpherical3DNoise = function (c, x, y, z) {
  var nx = x / c;
  var ny = y / c;
  var rdx = nx * 2 * Math.PI;
  var rdy = ny * Math.PI;
  var sinY = Math.sin(rdy + Math.PI);
  var sinRds = 2 * Math.PI;
  var a = sinRds * Math.sin(rdx) * sinY;
  var b = sinRds * Math.cos(rdx) * sinY;
  var d = sinRds * Math.cos(rdy);

  return this.get4DNoise(a, b, d, z);
};
```

Note in particular that *getSpherical3DNoise(c, x, y)* ends up sampling the three-dimensional pointvector $(a, b, d)$, given **only** an $( x,y )$ coordinate and circumference $c$

The second function, *getSpherical3DNoise(c, x, y, z)* seems like an incomprehensible follow-up to the previous function by sampling a *four*-dimensional vector $(a, b, d, z)$, $z$ being the Cartesian coordinate along the $z$-axis

These functions behave strangely to say the least. So they are either incomprehansably cleverly written. Or they warrant a rewrite.

Comment: what do you mean by the circumference of a sphere?

Comment: Circumference c would be the diameter multiplied by pi.

Comment: circumference $\neq$ diameter!

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, just realized my mistake. To clarify: $$ c = d.\pi $$ With d being the diameter

Comment: any idea what $x, y$ represent?

Comment: $(x, y)$ would be the Cartesian coordinates of a point on a circle. Please note that I just edited my question. Now I'm facing a problem concerning a circle, not a sphere. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: In the formula for $d$, what's $s\pi$? $2\pi$?

Comment: Yes exactly. That was an unlucky typo. I've corrected it.

Comment: If this is simply a piece of code sitting in your codebase but never used anywhere, then I would say just delete it. It is not worth reverse-engineering such things if you don't _know_ you need them. On the other hand, if the function is used somewhere then perhaps the places where it is used give hints about what it is supposed to do. The name of the function, and the names and types of its parameters, may also be hints.

Comment: The retranscript under LaTeX notation makes it less readable (and I suspect typos). Can you provide the genuine text (with code) ? This looks like a mapping transform of a rectangular grid to a spherical surface.

Comment: It is being used to sample noise on a spherical surface. I do believe that it doesn't work properly though. I have included the original code with comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\sin Y = -\sin rdY$, so $Y$ is redundant. Write down your 
formulae in clear, eliminating all the intermediate variables:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
a = -2 \pi \sin \frac {2 \pi x} c \sin \frac {\pi y} c \\
b = -2 \pi \cos \frac {2 \pi x} c \sin \frac {\pi y} c \\
d = 2 \pi \cos \frac {\pi y} c .
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Note that $a^2 + b^2 + d^2 = 4 \pi ^2$ and that the mapping $(x,y) \mapsto (a,b,d)$ is injective. Therefore, what these formulae do is to map the square $[0,c) \times [0,c)$ (points in it being represented by $(x,y)$ and $c$ being some physical, non-mathematical parameter) onto some part of the sphere centered in $(0,0,0)$ and of radius $2 \pi$. (Note that when I say "square" I mean the "full", "solid" square, but when I say "sphere" I mean just the surface, not the solid body.)

I have deleted the previous version of my answer, it was needlessly detailed. Please note, though, that the programmer chose to work with a certain convention regarding the orientation of the axes and the measurement of the angles in $\Bbb R ^3$ that is not among the several ones commonly used in mathematics.

Comment: This is very helpful! Please note that I've included the original source and more context into my question, this might give more insight.

Comment: This clarifies a lot, thank you.  It does raise one question though. What is the significance of $a^2 + b^2 + d^2 = 4 \pi ^2$? $4 \pi ^2$ would be the surface area of a sphere with radius one, correct?

Comment: @fauxnoir: The equation of the sphere of center $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and radius $r$ is $(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 + (z - z_0)^2 = r^2$. In your case, $r$ happens to be $2 \pi$, so squared gives you $4 \pi ^2$. Don't look for other significance, everything else is just a coincidence. I am still suspicious, though, of such a value for a radius. On a different note, the area of a sphere is $4 \pi r^2$, so in your case this would give $16 \pi ^3$. And no, for $r=1$ you get $4 \pi$ (no square for $\pi$).

Comment: I think I fully understand what's going on now... I believe the radius may have been picked because the square is being mapped to an imaginary sphere... Now that things make some sense mathematically I believe that in context of what they're trying to achieve it's pure gibberish, which is hard to realize when what you are trying to achieve is noise... That being said, my noise looks a lot better now!

Comment: @fauxnoir: I do not know what an imaginary sphere is. The ones on this page are very real, though.

Comment: That is very true. I think the correct word would have been *arbitrary*.

Answer (score 2):

It is all very strange! Suppose $(x,y)=(r x',ry')$ so that $(x',y')=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ is some point on the unit circle. Then we have
$$
\begin{align}
a&=2\pi\cdot\cos(x'-\pi/2)\cdot\cos(-y'/2-\pi/2)\\
b&=2\pi\cdot\sin(x'-\pi/2)\cdot\cos(-y'/2-\pi/2)\\
d&=2\pi\cdot\sin(-y'/2-\pi/2)
\end{align}
$$
This can be interpreted as a point on a $2\pi$-radius sphere in the $(a,b,d)$-plane, first rotated by an angle of $(x'-\pi/2)$ radians, then rotated away from the $(a,b)$-plane into the third dimension by an angle of $(-y'/2-\pi/2$. Strange!

---

I tried plotting what it does - it forms an 8-shaped curve on a sphere of radius $2\pi$. I promised to add a plot, and here it is:

[image]

The point $A=(x',y')$ traverses the unit circle and makes the point $B=(a,b,d)$ traverse an 8-shaped curve on the $2\pi$-sphere.

Comment: Thank you. I've also added some more context to my original question. It may help

Comment: The original unit circle is supposed to be a two-dimensional 'slice' of a sphere. If a z-dimension was added then the unit circle would increase or shrink in radius as the sphere was traversed. Then perhaps point B would describe a pattern that could fully 'wrap' over the $2\pi$-sphere?

Comment: Here's an [image](http://benchung.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/uvs-texture-sampler.jpg) of what I previously described